# Learning sources on cavity QED

Tags: superconducting-quantum-computing, circuit-qed

Recently, I have been studying lecture notes on Circuit QED by Steve Girvin to learn about superconducting circuits. I am currently in the chapter about cavity QED. The description in the notes are good, but I would like to learn more about them in a rigorous manner. Hence, I am looking for learning resources on the topic.

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

Some resources I am using during my studies:

- Circuit Quantum Electrodynamics (co-authored by S. Girvin): https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.12667
- A Quantum Engineer's Guide to Superconducting Qubits: https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.06560
- Qiskit Textbook: https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/cQED-JC-SW.html

Another resource which I also liked to get into the topic, but might be too slow depending on your pace is the Qiskit Summer School 2020 videos, Lesson  from Lesson 16 to Lesson 21: https://youtu.be/eZJjQGu85Ps

Comment: Thank you for your reply